# Como escapar aspas no PostgreSql?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Tenho uma função no postgresql `function f_criaproduto(p_texto text)`, eu tenho que passar da seguinte forma `f_criaproduto(' meu produto é 'televisao' da melhor qualidade')`.

Como eu posso escapar as aspas no texto?

Comment: Qual erro aparece? o problema é anular as aspas simples?

Answer (score 12):

Pra escapar aspas, você pode duplicá-las. Exemplo:

```
f_criaproduto('meu produto é ''televisao'' da melhor qualidade')
```

Para evitar o problema de ter muitas aspas para dar escape, você pode utilizar a sintaxe de dollars:

```
$$meu produto é 'televisao' da melhor qualidade$$
```

Note que, nesse caso, a string é definida com um par de dolares ao invés de aspas. Caso a sua string também tenha dolares, você pode utilizar uma tag para isso, definindo ela entre os dolares. Por exemplo, para definir a string `minha 'televisao' custa uma boa $!`

```
$string$minha 'televisao' custa uma boa $!$string$
```

Ainda é possivel usar o caracter `\` você precisa de duas coisas:

1. no arquivo de configuração, você deve abilitar `standard_conforming_strings`:

   `standard_conforming_strings = off`
2. Iniciar a suas strings com `E`. Exemplo:

   `E'meu produto é \'televisao\' da melhor qualidade'`

Mas essa ultima opção é antiga e deve ser evitada se possível

Answer (score 9):

Basta duplicar as aspas simples para gerar um *escape*.

Exemplo:

```sql
f_criaproduto(' meu produto é ''televisao'' da melhor qualidade')
```

Comment: Valeu resolveu meu problema..

Answer (score 0):

O delimitador $ pode ser utilizado para separar expressões. Exemplo:

```
DO $_$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE $$ || SELECT * FROM alunos || $$;
END;
$_$
```

Repare que a utilização do $ pode ser nomeada: $x$ ou $teste$. Não se esqueça que é necessário fechar da mesma forma que você começou